# Forwarding socket.io/engine.io connection to another server

Tags: node.js, sockets, networking, socket.io, engine.io

We are trying to find the best approach to our load balancing issue with websockets.

Websocket can initially connect to any server, that server will run some logic and then if needed it will "redirect" the client to appropriate server.

Is there a way in socket.io/engine.io to redirect/forward connections?

Something like:

```
io.use(function(socket){
    // ... logic
    if(logic === true){
        socket.redirect("172.10.10.2:3000");
    }
});
```

I am aware of that `socket.redirect` is not valid function but is there something like that?

Comment: You can send a socket.io message back to the client and tell it what IP/port to connect to and let the client listen for that message and when it receives it, drop the current connection and reconnect to the new server as in:  `socket.emit('redirect', '172.10.10.2:3000')`

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes! that is about how far we got, unfortunately though it happens too late. I cannot find information about some kind of middleware for socket.io that would intercept the connection flow? if I use `io.use()` it works only for the root namespace

Answer (score 0):

socket.io not support something like `socket.redirect`

But you can use Nginx to make proxy for load balance and use [socket.io-redis](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis) to make adapter for socket.io and handle `if(logic === true){}` in multiple nodes.